# Why does Firefox terminate my applet after 20 seconds?

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I have a simple applet on a web page like this. (This is a test case cut down from a more complicated applet).

```
package test;

import java.applet.Applet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleLoopApplet extends Applet
{
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("SimpleLoopApplet invoked");
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Sleep for 1 second");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Applet thread interrupted while sleeping");
                }
            }
        }
        finally {}
    }
}
```

On Firefox 3.6.8 on one computer this applet will run for 20 seconds and then exit abruptly, as if the VM is terminating (The java console will disappear; the Java icon will remain in the system tray until I mouse over it; the finally block is never reached).

It's consistently 20 seconds. 20  "Sleep for 1 second"s printed from the above code, if I extend the sleep to 5 seconds, then 4 messages are printed before termination.

In IE and Chrome on the same computer, the loop will continue on indefinitely, as it will in Firefox 3.6.8 on a different computer.

Can anyone suggest why the applet might terminate in this way?

Comment: Thanks to josefx and stacker who came up with almost identical and essentially correct answers. FWIW, putting the loop in `start` instead of `init` made no difference, but creating a separate thread did resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the applet [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)

> **init Method**
>
> The init method is useful for one-time
> initialization that doesn't take very
> long. The init method typically
> contains the code that you would
> normally put into a constructor. The
> reason applets don't usually have
> constructors is that they aren't
> guaranteed to have a full environment
> until their init method is called.
> Keep the init method short so that
> your applet can load quickly.
>
> **start Method**
>
> Every applet that performs tasks after
> initialization (except in direct
> response to user actions) must
> override the start method. The start
> method starts the execution of the
> applet. It is good practice to return
> quickly from the start method. If you
> need to perform computationally
> intensive operations it might be
> better to start a new thread for this
> purpose.

It looks like you have to create your own thread for long running methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
Can anyone suggest why the applet might terminate in this way?
```

I haven't found an offical reference, but it looks like a timeout for initialization. 
You could put your code in the start method which shouldn't have any timeouts like that.

From [Javadoc init()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html)

> A subclass of Applet should override
>   this method if it has initialization
>   to perform. For example, an applet
>   with threads would use the init method
>   to create the threads and the destroy
>   method to kill them.

I guess you need to a long running initialization, therefore you should start a thread for that in the init() method.

Answer (score 1):

There is bugs for on
[firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626362).

The only solution I have found is to use java less than 1.6_21. From 1.6_21, firefox 3.0 and 3.6 is broken. Fortunately everything should be working in firefox 4.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I haven't had any problems since I added a separate thread for the long running process. Fortunately (I think!) officially, I only have to support IE 7 and 8.

Comment: We are in worse situation since oure company only supports Firefox. For now we only tell our clients to install lower version of java and were waiting for firefox 4 to come. Using threads is one option but its only a workaround to this problem not real solution :). There is also bug for this problem on java. If your interested try looking for bug 7012740 on http://bugs.sun.com/